# fail to load sklearn.datasets import load_iris

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
dataset = load_iris()
```

below error keep occurring :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\a80017362\PycharmProjects\Abbas_Huawei\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\_base.py", line 384, in load_iris
    data, target, target_names = load_data(module_path, 'iris.csv')
  File "C:\Users\a80017362\PycharmProjects\Abbas_Huawei\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\_base.py", line 236, in load_data
    n_samples = int(temp[0])
**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'sepal-length'**
```

Comment: re-install `sklearn`

Comment: thx a ton! it is working

Comment: cheers. bests. !